# How to disable logs on my soajs app

Tags: node.js, debugging, console.log, soajs

Our soajs application is logging some `info/debug/...` text on standard output:

```
[2016-08-10T14:13:27.283Z]  INFO: app2/... (/.../soajs/...:401): Adding Service Maintenance Routes ...
[2016-08-10T14:13:27.283Z]  INFO: app2/... (/.../soajs/...:401): service started on port: 4020
```

...

- Is there a way to configure soajs in silence mode (No log) ?
- Or even better, is there a way to provide my own logger that I can control ?

Answer (score 0):

To log any message you can use 
soajs.log.info or soajs.log.error  functions
You cannot disable the default messages coming from a soajs service. 
Unless you go to that service and comment the logs there or override the soajs.log functions defined in soajs core by making them output nothing.